# How to access raw video data while MPMoviePlayer is playing a video stream

Tags: ios, metadata, mpmovieplayer

I am using a MPMoviePlayerController to play a video stream. Because there is some metadata embedded in the raw data that I need to parse out, I need to find a way to get access to the raw  video data. Does anyone know a way of doing it? The embedded metadata is not ID3 tagged, so I cannot use the built-in metadata functionality to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. There is no way of parsing out any format of metadata other than ID3 tags with Apple's MPMoviePlayerController or AVFoundation framework. You will have to go for a 3rd party video player if you need to do so.